# Pipe Delimited info Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this column which is Pipe delimited.

```
ID         Col1
1000        Class1|Sec2|Tom|Brady
1001        Class1|Sec2|Row4|Tim|Tebow
1002        Class2|Sec2|Row3|Huck|Fin
1003        Class2|Sec2|Tom|Sawyer
1004        Class10|Sec1|Rowq|sa|
```

Now how can I just get the names after the last pipe.

O/P

```
 ID         Col1
1000        Brady
1001        Tebow
1002        Fin
1003        Sawyer
1004
```

Can anyone please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table. It should look like this

```
ID     Class   Section   Firstname   Lastname
1000   Class1  Sec2      Tom         Brady
```